# Как правильно спроектировать android приложение самоучитель?

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, kotlin

Пишу самоучитель состоящий из 50 уроков, каждый урок это текст и несколько аудиофайлов, причем расположение текста и аудиофайлов в каждом уроке разное, так же необходимо выделять некоторые слова в тексте и при клике воспроизводить звук, из решений нашел только spannableString, так как у webview есть ограничения.

1. Как все правильно реализовать создавать 50 активити или фрагментов? либо динамически формировать это все в одном активити?
2. Что выбрать для хранения текста json или sqlite?

Comment: Вы уверены, что аудио - это хорошая идея?

Comment: это самоучитель языка, аудио необходимо для чтоб понять как произносить определенные звуки

Comment: @MuscleCode, такие вещи лучше подгружать с сети, apk не резиновый же

Comment: около 160 мб получится примерно

Comment: @MuscleCode ааа, такого языка. я то подумал яп